# Dividing the rotor circuit by slip in induction motor

Tags: circuit-analysis, motor, ac, electromagnetism, induction-motor

In [this article](http://electricalacademia.com/induction-motor/three-phase-induction-motor-equivalent-circuit/) equation (3), just after figure 5, they divided everything in the equation for current by slip. I understand that current remains the same when doing this, but voltage and power would change by dividing everything by slip. Why do they do this and how is it equivalent when analyzing a circuit?

Comment: Were you ok with equation 2?

Comment: Ya I I just don’t understand why everything was divided by slip and how energy conservation is that same when doing so